# Python import subpakcage of subpackage of subpackage

Tags: python, import, module

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

[image]

When I do

`import app.model as m`

the statement doesn't show any error

But when I do

`import app.model.core as c`

there is an error like

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'`

I fail to understand the behaviour. Any help, hint or pointers will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: If you do `import app.model as m` and then print the value of `m.__file__`, what do you get?

Comment: Thats is '<path to shutterdeck?>/app/model/__init__.py'

Comment: Are `app/model/__int__.py` and `app/model/core/__init__.py` empty?

Comment: @PeterWood: No, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with a dummy package structure.

Comment: @Mayank: Do you really get `AttributeError`?  You should get something like `No module named app.model.core`.

Comment: Perhaps `app/__init__.py` is defining something named `model`?

Comment: Oops! Its no more an error!! I wasted sometime to realize its an issue with pycharm (Or probably my understanding of it). I restarted pycharm and it works. I was running those import commands on pycharm python console.  I made __init__.py empty and I think pycharm needs to be closed and reopened!... I should close the question. Thanks all for the time.